# How to execute .bat file to run test cases from controller / job / service

Tags: java, grails, servlets, batch-file

I want to invoke batch file from .job file to execute my test-cases periodically, for this 
I wrote below code in the job file

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:testcase.bat")
```

above line is calling batch file, printing the batch file commands and i am not getting any output.

But the same thing worked with static java file and can able to run the testcases.

please let me know how to call batch file from my Controller / Service / Job

batch file contains below commands :

```
:d
cd D:\workspace\MyApp
grails teat-app
```

Comment: [Read this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) (all 4 pages) and update your question with new error details you found out. As far now it's impossible to answer the question since the error details are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Call the windows command processor to run your batchfile instead of assuming the operating system will automatically figure it out. Code like the following works for me.

```
Process batchFileProc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\batchfile.bat")
```