# Java How do I Execute a Batch File when Server Status boolean is false?

Tags: java, batch-file, status

Objective: I want to make a java program containing a boolean that checks every 5 minutes to see if my games server (cloudnine1999.no-ip.org:port 43594)

Purpose: To restart my game server if it crashes

Problem: Not sure how to check if a server is online using java.

Programs Function: If the boolean returns false(meaning the server is offline) I want the java program to open a specific batch file so the server starts up(in case the server crashes)

I tried finding something on google but I didn't find anything helpful and I'm not quite advanced enough of a coder to figure this out on my own, all I need is someone to instruct me/point me in the right direction of coding a server status checker with java and I can do the rest from there.

I may not be able to respond to your answers until around 4PM Central Us&Canada time zone.

Comment: What do you mean containing a boolean? A boolean method? A boolean member variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988953/how-to-check-server-is-up

Comment: @sbk, That's a little bit different than what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Charlie, I'm trying to make a boolean method that returns the boolean value true if the server is online and false if the server is offline.

Comment: @user2072802 that will check the server, this could call your batch job: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614182/how-to-execute-bat-file-to-run-test-cases-from-controller-job-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Socket` to check if the server is up (if it can connect to the IP and Port without throwing an exception). Be careful, some servers don't like these 'empty' connections.

```
try{
    new Socket("cloudnine1999.no-ip.org", 43594).close();
}catch(IOException ex){
    // Server probably down, restart it...
}catch(Exception ex){
    // Some  other problem, likely DNS or security related.
}
```

Use `ProcessBuilder` to start it up again.

Answer (score 0):

Shell Script Solution :

I am assuming that server is a Java EE server. Servers are kicked by "bat" on Windows or "shell" script on Linux/Unix. For UNIX/LINUX :  The most easiest solution is code a logic, in the SHELL Script that kicks of the server, to LOG the PID of the JVM in a file when the server is started. Then you write a simple shell script to monitor the PID logged by using the command "ps -aef | grep " . If the PID is not there , start the server. You should run this script as the same user who starts the server in its original place. A second solution is to "ps auxww | grep java" . Note the server varaiables which identifies your server. If you run the command , you will know.

Java Solution :

Every server has an admin port which can be monitored using a HTTP URL. Oh,well you can also hit the application url. With a Java Program you can test the connection. If the HTTP Response code is 200 - you are good and if its other than 200 like - 500 / 400 , server may be assumed dead. Then you need to kickoff the server start script.

Comment: I found a tutorial like this but what I'm trying to do wouldn't work with that. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user2072802 care to share link ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the link, I'm using a public computer at the moment, the computer files reset daily, so the history is gone. The tutorial I believe was something to do with finding the server status of a web server, however I am not using one.